Why is writing into an existing file faster than writing a new file?
I have noticed strange limitations in Windows regarding file-writing performance onto an SSD: namely, I seem to be unable to write into a single file with more than some 3-4 GB/s. Writing multiple files simultaneously, I can fill an empty 4TB disk at 6 GB/s, but not into a single file, and unfortunately this is what I need to do.
Enter fio, which allows me to write 6 GB/s into a single file provided that this file is pre-allocated. Otherwise, I can write at only the previously mentioned 3-4 GB/s.
Here's fio.txt:
[global]
thread
bs=1M
rw=write
iodepth=8
direct=1

[job1]
filename=fio.bin
size=100G

And then I run
fio fio.txt

twice, resulting in the following output:
E:\>fio fio.txt
job1: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=windowsaio, iodepth=8
fio-3.38
Starting 1 thread
job1: Laying out IO file (1 file / 102400MiB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [W(1)][100.0%][w=4271MiB/s][w=4271 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
job1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=5732: Wed Oct 23 01:48:16 2024
  write: IOPS=4253, BW=4254MiB/s (4460MB/s)(100GiB/24073msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=200, max=1630, avg=234.47, stdev=25.03
    clat (nsec): min=490, max=3012.7k, avg=941622.54, stdev=473495.82
     lat (usec): min=231, max=3339, avg=1176.10, stdev=472.11
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  217],  5.00th=[  227], 10.00th=[  241], 20.00th=[  461],
     | 30.00th=[  676], 40.00th=[  717], 50.00th=[  930], 60.00th=[ 1156],
     | 70.00th=[ 1221], 80.00th=[ 1401], 90.00th=[ 1614], 95.00th=[ 1647],
     | 99.00th=[ 1762], 99.50th=[ 1795], 99.90th=[ 1860], 99.95th=[ 1942],
     | 99.99th=[ 2089]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 4041, max= 4294, per=100.00%, avg=4254.81, stdev=36.63, samples=48
   iops        : min= 4041, max= 4294, avg=4254.54, stdev=36.74, samples=48
  lat (nsec)   : 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%
  lat (usec)   : 2=0.21%, 4=0.01%, 20=0.01%, 250=11.45%, 500=15.97%
  lat (usec)   : 750=14.30%, 1000=14.11%
  lat (msec)   : 2=43.94%, 4=0.02%
  cpu          : usr=12.46%, sys=12.46%, ctx=0, majf=0, minf=0
  IO depths    : 1=0.2%, 2=28.5%, 4=57.0%, 8=14.3%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=87.5%, 8=12.5%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,102400,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=8

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=4254MiB/s (4460MB/s), 4096MiB/s-4254MiB/s (4295MB/s-4460MB/s), io=100GiB (107GB), run=24073-24073msec

E:\>fio fio.txt
job1: (g=0): rw=write, bs=(R) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (W) 1024KiB-1024KiB, (T) 1024KiB-1024KiB, ioengine=windowsaio, iodepth=8
fio-3.38
Starting 1 thread
Jobs: 1 (f=0): [f(1)][100.0%][w=6007MiB/s][w=6007 IOPS][eta 00m:00s]
job1: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=4788: Wed Oct 23 01:48:36 2024
  write: IOPS=6065, BW=6066MiB/s (6361MB/s)(100GiB/16881msec); 0 zone resets
    slat (usec): min=27, max=421, avg=38.99, stdev= 6.16
    clat (usec): min=356, max=2708, avg=1279.41, stdev=78.91
     lat (usec): min=436, max=2744, avg=1318.40, stdev=78.68
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[ 1156],  5.00th=[ 1172], 10.00th=[ 1172], 20.00th=[ 1205],
     | 30.00th=[ 1237], 40.00th=[ 1270], 50.00th=[ 1287], 60.00th=[ 1303],
     | 70.00th=[ 1319], 80.00th=[ 1336], 90.00th=[ 1352], 95.00th=[ 1385],
     | 99.00th=[ 1418], 99.50th=[ 1450], 99.90th=[ 2057], 99.95th=[ 2278],
     | 99.99th=[ 2540]
   bw (  MiB/s): min= 3783, max= 6220, per=99.03%, avg=6006.92, stdev=413.39, samples=34
   iops        : min= 3783, max= 6220, avg=6006.65, stdev=413.46, samples=34
  lat (usec)   : 500=0.01%, 750=0.01%, 1000=0.03%
  lat (msec)   : 2=99.84%, 4=0.12%
  cpu          : usr=11.85%, sys=5.92%, ctx=0, majf=0, minf=0
  IO depths    : 1=0.1%, 2=0.1%, 4=0.1%, 8=99.9%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.1%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued rwts: total=0,102400,0,0 short=0,0,0,0 dropped=0,0,0,0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=8

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=6066MiB/s (6361MB/s), 4096MiB/s-6066MiB/s (4295MB/s-6361MB/s), io=100GiB (107GB), run=16881-16881msec

Why might writing into the existing file make a difference compared to writing into a new file? And, most importantly, is there a way for me to achieve high writing speeds without having to pre-allocate a file, e.g., by preparing the file system in a certain way?
(I have seen the related questions, but they related to smaller files, Linux (where I can write 6 GB/s into the same file), Java, or find the opposite effect altogether.)

Not really a programming question, but an interesting one none the less. One could imagine that expanding the file requires more meta data updates than just writing to already allocated space, but that's mere speculation on my part.

What's wrong with preallocating the file if that's what it takes to meet your speed requirement?

@AndreHenle I am working on data acquisition, and I do not know beforehand how much data I will be acquiring. So I would have to re-preallocate during the acquisition, which is not impossible but requires sophisticated error handling and post-close trimming of the file.

Poking around I found this cross-site duplicate for Linux, and a seemingly related problem with mercurial which suggested that Procmon can confirm where the problem lies. If I had Windows OS I could test this theory, and make it an answer, for now it's a guess. -- @500 is on the correct track.
